# Outlook ItemAdd event raises also with sync

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook Addin which will prompt the user to save an email after it is sent.

Works fine until the user has sent the email with his phone and exchange syncs the sent items folder on the users desktop. How can i only prompt the user when the email is sent on his desktop.

So can i check if email has been sent from current device only.

Thanks so much.

Solution

Raise two events :

.ItemSend =>

```
mail.UserProperties.Add("NameUserProperty", OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo);
mail.UserProperties["NameUserProperty"].Value = true;
mail.Save();
```

.ItemAdd (Sent Folder) =>

```
if(mail.UserProperties["NameUserProperty"].Value == true)
{
 // record message
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to properly capture this is to set a flag at the time the item is sent (MailItem.Send) and then set a watch on the Sent Items folder to look for a message with the same Subject when it is added to the folder (via ItemAdd).

Comment: Yes, i will set a UserProperty on the .ItemSend event.
When mail is added in sent folder .ItemAdd event i check if userproperty exists. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Application.ItemSend` event - it fires only for the messages sent by the local instance of Outlook.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the sent data because the mail is still in compose state

Comment: Do you mean the MailItem.Sent property? Everything else will be there.

Comment: Yes our customer wants to record the message with the sent date .